# SQL, invoice statements, current and past dues

Tags: sql

New to SQL, understand the basic queries, trying to write something a little more advanced than my knowledge, and need some help if anyone can offer it.  I've already tried template codes and tailoring to my needs, with no success.

I'm working with 1 table, and trying to get the query to display customers current balance for 0-30 days, and any past due dates between 30-60 , 60-90 , 90-120, 120+ days.

```
table: c_inv_h
columns: comp_code, cust_code, inv_num, inv_date, inv_tp, inv_amt, inv_tax1, inv_tax2
```

example data

```
comp_code, cust_code, inv_num, inv_date, inv_tp, inv_amt, inv_tax1, inv_tax2
M1, 100068, 1, 2016-08-11, RCPT, 103.48, 4.5, 8.98
M1, 100068, 2, 2016-07-11, RCPT, 103.48, 4.5, 8.98
M1, 100068, 3, 2016-06-11, RCPT, 103.48, 4.5, 8.98
M1, 200027, 4, 2016-05-11, RCPT, 103.48, 4.5, 8.98
M1, 200027, 5, 2016-04-11, RCPT, 103.48, 4.5, 8.98
```

What I want the query to show:

```
comp_code, cust_code, CurrentBalance, 30-60, 60-90, 90-120, 120+
M1, 100068, 116.96, 233.92, 0, 0, 0
M1, 200027, 0, 233.92, 0, 0, 0
M1, 200027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 233.92
```

What I've tried so far

```
SELECT comp_code, cust_code, inv_num, inv_date, sum(inv_amt) + sum(inv_tax1)
+ sum(inv_tax2) as InvoiceTotal,
DATEDIFF(day, inv_date, sysdate as Numberofdays, 'CurrentBalance' = 
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,inv_date, sysdate < 30 then InvoiceTotal END,
'30_days' = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, inv_date, sysdate between 30 AND 60
Then InvoiceTotal WHEN DATEDIFF(day, inv_date, sysdate > 90 Then
InvoiceTotal END
FROM c_inv_h
WHERE comp_code='M1'
GROUP BY comp_code, cust_code
```

This is probably way off from what I'm trying to achieve but I"m trying to work through it.

Much thanks in advance!!

Comment: Alan welcome to stackoverflow!  You have a good start to your question, but should also include what your desired result is based on your example data and show us something you have tried.  Don't worry if it is way off or doesn't work it just helps us know we are helping you not doing it for you and could yield some additional insight into your desired logic.

Comment: Thank Matt.  I edited my posting.

Comment: You can use conditional aggregation to create a Pivot Table like that.  But depending on which database/rdbms (sql-server, oracle, mysql) there may be some other options available to you what system are you using?  Also is it possible to put a row of daa in the what you want your query to show it helps people visualize better

Comment: I've inputted a sample row as you requested.   Using mysql.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track thinking of **conditional aggregation**.  You just had to remove the columns not involved in aggregation and clean up the syntax errors.

```
SELECT
    comp_code
    ,cust_code
    ,SUM(CASE
          WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),inv_date) < 30
          THEN COALESCE(inv_amt,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax1,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax2,0.00)
          ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS CurrentBalance
    ,SUM(CASE
          WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),inv_date) >= 30 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),inv_date) < 60
          THEN COALESCE(inv_amt,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax1,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax2,0.00)
          ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS "30-60"
    ,SUM(CASE
          WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),inv_date) >= 60 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),inv_date) < 90
          THEN COALESCE(inv_amt,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax1,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax2,0.00)
          ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS "60-90"
    ,SUM(CASE
          WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),inv_date) >= 90 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),inv_date) < 120
          THEN COALESCE(inv_amt,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax1,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax2,0.00)
          ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS "90-120"
    ,SUM(CASE
          WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),inv_date) >= 120
          THEN COALESCE(inv_amt,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax1,0.00) + COALESCE(inv_tax2,0.00)
          ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS "120+"
FROM
    c_inv_h
WHERE
    comp_code='M1'
GROUP BY
    comp_code, cust_code
;
```

I am using COALESCE to make sure there is a value because when adding columns if you add 1 + NULL + 1 the result will be NULL.  When using an aggregate function e.g. SUM() it will ignore the NULL values.  Because you are using both depending on your dataset you could need to assign 0 to NULL which COALESCE helps with.

Next I am not using BETWEEN because BETWEEN is inclusive of both sides of the comparison so if you say between 30 AND 60 for one column and between 60 and 90 on the other and the amount is 60 days past due it would be in both columns.

Last your example output isn't correct for the example data you provided because the dates are 5,36,66,97, and 127 days apart but I am pretty sure I understand what you wanted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Please bare with me, slowly learning and understanding what you've written.  I've tried testing that script, and I was getting errors thrown at me, such as invalid table name, so I took out the @ from @c_inv_h, then I got error for DATEDIFF being an invalid identifier.  I then tried to replace DATEDIFF with STARTDATE, and that is an invalid identifier as well. 

'java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00903: invalid table name', 

'java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier'

Comment: sorry I left the @ symbol in there I used sql-server table variable to test and build the query.  I also hadn't change a few syntax things to mysql version.  I built the query quick based on looking at your query and I guess I should have done it in mysql to begin with.  SQLFiddle is a site that lets you test some code in different databases here is a link to a test that shows you the updated answer is working now.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40271/4

Comment: Thanks Matt, I was able to get your script to work in MySQL, then I tried it on my company servers database, and to no avai.  I'm an idiot, database is running on Oracle and not mysql, so I'm trying to tweak it to Oracles function names.

'
SELECT comp_code, cust_code, CASE WHEN TO_DATE(sysdate) - TO_DATE(inv_date) < 30 THEN COALESCE(inv_amt,0.00) ELSE 0 AS CurrentBalance
FROM c_inv_h
WHERE comp_code='M1'
GROUP BY comp_code, cust_code'
'
do you see where I'm going wrong on this?

Comment: honestly it is hard to follow code in a comment can you update your question and format it there.  But TO_DATE is an issue, although I doubt you need to cast the values because they are already dates so the syntax may just be (sysdate - inv_date) < 30, etc.  a similar syntax works in sql-server

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you.  You were absolutely correct in removing TO_DATE.  I was able to get the query to work in Oracle once removed and following through with your syntax.

Comment: awesome glad to hear it worked for you please accept my answer here is a link about how/why etc if you are curious/need http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work